# DRF convert datetime to timestamp in response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My model contains a datetime field, I want to convert it to timestamp when requested. Here is the `get` handler for the response:

```
def get(self, request, pk):
    journal = Journal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serializer = LogSerializer(journal)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the response:

```
{
  ...blah...
  "created": "2015-12-02T08:57:16.881528Z",
}
```

I tried this to get the unix timestamp:

```
from django.utils.dateformat import format

def get(self, request, pk):
    journal = Journal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    journal.created = format(journal.created, 'U') #error, because the LogSerializer expects a datetime object instead of a string
    serializer = LogSerializer(journal)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my serializer and model:

```
class LogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Journal


class Journal(Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Is there a way to tell the JSONRender to do the following:

```
if fieldName == 'created': 
    data['created'] = convert_to_timestamp(data['created'])
```

or Should I just modify the stringified data:

```
content = JSONRender(serializer.data)
... find the position of the time string in content and replace it with the timestamp ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` to achieve the same.

```
response_created_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_created_date')

def get_created_date(self, obj):
    return convert_to_timestamp(obj.created)
```

Click [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for more info.